# Why does emptymessage property do auto validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation, input, telerik, rad-controls

I am using Radnumericbox like that,

```
 <telerik:RadNumericTextBox CssClass="app-input" ID="txtUnivaPerfTreshold" runat="server" MaxValue="100" MinValue="1" MaxLength="4" Value="30" EmptyMessage="between %1 - %100" Width="130px" Type="Percent">
```

When I add EmptyMessage property to radnumerictextbox , on page submit textbox  do auto validation. And red border appears out of textbox. If I dont add empty massage property to radnumerictextbox on page submit textbox is not do autovalidation. I want to use Empty message property but I dont want any validation and red border.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. If you are `EmptyMessage` and `MaxLenght` property in same item, telerik use autovalidation it's own. If you delete one of `EmptyMessage` or `MaxLenght` propery in item, autovalidation does'nt work. There is no way for use `EmptyMessage` and `MaxLenght` in same item without autovalidation.

You find details in here : http://www.telerik.com/forums/about-empty-message-property

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox CssClass="app-input" ID="txtUnivaPerfTreshold" runat="server"
                               MaxValue="100" MinValue="1" MaxLength="4" Value="30" EmptyMessage="between %1 - %100" Width="130px" Type="Percent">
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="submit" runat="server" />
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

to make sure I see any such styling, but none was added.
Take a look at the surrounding code to see if anything else is affecting the control (custom validators, validation being set in the code-behind, etc.).

Finally, examine the rendered HTML to override the CSS you do not like. I think riError is the class the input will get when invalid, so you can remove borders and any other styling you don't want.